# How to display total number of items new to view shopping cart?

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart

So in a nut shell I have created a simple e commerce website using paypal add to cart buttons with no problems - Its only now I should of considered using an opencart source PHP/Mysql, but it's to late now as it's pretty much done. My question is, is how can I display the total number of items next to view cart? something like this (1) is there a simple way to do this? I'm really struggling to find an answer, is there a small piece of code I need to change in the view cart form? my website is here, there is no other problems. [www.diva-wear.co.uk](http://www.diva-wear.co.uk)

Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I meant NEXT to view shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

There is not going to be anything you can do with the button code itself, but you can track what your buyer is adding to the cart. If you enable and use PHP sessions, this can be as easy as storing the count of items in a session variable that you display next to the cart button.

You can run something similar to this when someone adds an item to their cart.

```html
<?php 

session_start();

$_SESSION['items_count'] = $_SESSION['items_count'] + 1;
```